# Remove all Vim undo files in all but one directory

Tags: vim, find, wildcards, rm

I just realized that I have tons of Vim undo (`.un~`) files sprinkled around my file system. I'd like to delete all of these files except in one directory—`~/.tmp`. My first problem is that I can't seem to find a Unix command to delete these things. For example, I have a file name that looks like this:

`.myfile.txt.un~`

I've tried, `rm -f *.un`, `rm -f *.un\~`, `rm -f *.un*`, etc. and I can't seem to find any command that can delete these files. How can I delete these files?

Secondly, I'd like to write a command with find that can visit all my directories and delete these files, with the exception of the `~/.tmp` directory. I'm quite afraid of executing this command incase it's wrong. Can anyone help be construct a find command to do this? Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: You can keep all the undo files in one directory by setting `undodir` in .vimrc

Answer (score 5):

These commands didn't work because wildcard patterns omit [dot files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_file#Unix_and_Unix-like_environments) (files whose name begins with the character `.`) unless the dot appears explicitly in the pattern. So `*.un~` matches `yourfile.txt.un~` but not `.myfile.txt.un~`, whereas `.*.un~` does match `.myfile.txt.un~`.

You should be able to use `find(1)` for this (`find` wildcard matching doesn't treat dot files specially):

```
find / -name "*.un~" -not -path "~/.tmp/*" -delete
```

That tells find to search `/` for all files matching `*.un~` that aren't in `~/.tmp` and delete them. If you take off `-delete` it will just output a list, so you can check and make sure it's not going to delete the wrong things. You also might want to throw `-mount` in there to stop it from searching other filesystems you have mounted

Answer (score 4):

`*` does not expand dot files. You'll have to say e.g.:

```
rm ./.*.un~
```

If you use `find`, which probably would be the easiest, I'd use

```
find -iname ".*.un~" ...
```

instead of:

```
find -iname "*.un~" ...
```

As the latter would match `foo.un~` as well as `.foo.un~`.

And, yes, do a dry run first to be sure you have the correct matches.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize that wildcards do not expand after dotfiles. Much appreciated.

Comment: @turtle You can click the checkmark next to an answer to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it